# Let $|H|=pq$ where $q$ and $p$ are both prime. Show that $H$ is not always cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $|H|=pq$ where $q$ and $p$ are both prime. Show that $H$ is not always cyclic.

I'm quite stumped on this problem. All I know about $H$ is that its order is the multiplication of two primes.

I'm sure theirs a counterexample that shows that the statement is not true but I'm having trouble understanding why.

It seems that no matter what I pick for $p$ & $q$, For example setting $p=q=2$ still results in a group of order 4 which could still be cyclic, So I still get an order which could lead to the group being cyclic.

Comment: There are two groups of order 4. Only one is cyclic. So a group of order $pq$ is not _always_ cyclic.

Comment: From your use of the phrase "could lead to the group being cyclic" I wonder if you're clear on the difference between "not always cyclic" and "must  be non-cyclic". Your phrase sounds like you're thinking of the latter concept while the question is asking about the former.

Comment: Well I think this question is wrong (or badly worded if you want to be generous). All groups of order $15$ are cyclic, so the claim is false when $p=3$ and $q=5$.

Comment: Yes, it is very poorly worded. I think there's going to be a lot of arguing over different conflicting interpretations and we won't be helping the original poster see the difference between "not for all X" and "for all not X".

Answer (score 1):

Let $p=2$ and $q=3$. Then the symmetric group $S_3$ on $pq=6$ elements is not cyclic.

Alternatively, simply note that when $p=q=2$ like you tried, the Klein four-group on $pq=4$ elements is not cyclic (all non-trivial elements have order 2).

Comment: But it's not true when $p=3$ and $q=5$.

Comment: @DerekHolt The question did not say "for all $p,q$"...

Comment: But that is what the wording of the question implies.

Comment: @DerekHolt False. The question says "show that semiprime-order groups are not necessarily cyclic", which amounts to finding just one counterexample for some $p,q$. I gave two.

Comment: I can't see the words "semiprime-order groups" anywhere in the question. It says "where $q$ and $p$ are both prime", and then asks the questions, so $q$ and $p$ have apparently been fixed before the question is asked. In any case, the student should not be given the additional problem of deciding which of two possible interpretations is correct.

Comment: @DerekHolt They haven't. If they were, then as you said, the only order-15 group is cyclic, so that can be ruled out.

Comment: Exactly - so the question as written is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

what is G? I am guessing you just mean H.

Every abelian group of order $pq$ ($p \not= q$) is automatically cyclic. So, if you want a non-cyclic group you have to move to the nonabelian case. An example of a non-cyclic group which has order a product of primes is the dihedral group, of order $2p$ ($2$ and $p$ are both primes).

Can you generalize this idea for arbitrary $p$ and $q$? Hint: Take semidirectproducts.